# POST Array through JSON foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

**The question:**

I have this array coming through a POST field

```
{"name":"sample","email":"a@sample.co.uk","comments":"test"}
```

I want to split it apart and run it through an array, so the end result would be

```
name sample
email a@sample.co.uk
comments test
```

What I have tried is this:

```
$a = $_POST['rawRequest'];
$a = json_encode($a);
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v <br />";
}
```

But it doesn't do anything, however when I test it with this variable (over using the POST)

```
$a = array("name" => 1,"email" => 2,"sample" => 3);
```

It works as expected.

**Trying to understand what is going on**

It is obviously because what I am dealing with here is two different types of array. However after endless google'ing I can't find anywhere which explains the difference (of the arrays below basically). So +1 to an explination which makes my relatively newbie mind understand what is happening and why it is wrong

```
{"name"=>"sample","email"=>"a@sample.co.uk"=>"comments":"test"}

{"name":"sample","email":"a@sample.co.uk","comments":"test"}
```

Comment: Wait a minute. What is the _raw_ input you get from `$_POST['rawRequest']`? You are calling `json_encode()` which doesn't make sense here. What is the value you started with from `$_POST`?

Comment: This is the value of that post field : {"name":"sample","email":"a@sample.co.uk","comments":"test"}

Comment: Ah, then you need to `json_decode()` it, not `json_encode()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The reason encode is in there is because I thought (possibly incorrectly) this is a string which needs to be converted in to a string

Answer (score 2):

$aa Isn't a array, is a JSON:

```
$a = $_POST['rawRequest'];
$aa = json_encode($a);
```

Thus, you can't use foreach in $aa.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decode a json string into an array instead of an object, use the 'Array' flag.

```
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
$data = '{"name":"sample","email":"a@sample.co.uk","comments":"test"}';
$json = json_decode($data,true);
foreach($json as $key=>$val){
 echo $key." - ".$val;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Check the output here

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ytn-kp0

You have done as

```
echo "\$a[$k] => $v <br />";
```

This would output as

```
$a[name] => sample
```

"$a" will be considered as string

You can do the way you are doing but you need to change the echo something as

```
echo $k ."=>" .$v. "<br />";
```

Since you are looping the array using foreach and $k will contain the key of the array and $v will be the value !!

Comment: You should explain why this would work instead of saying "try this"

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go. However I would appreciate a explanation as @RUJordan says. I want to learn what is actually happening rather than endlessly copying and pasting :)

Comment: @tim.baker I like you.

Comment: Yes added the answer with the explanation !!

Answer (score 0):

I have Json decoded the encoded array and looped it through a foreach below with comments explaining what each part does.

---

```
/* The Json encoded array.*/
$json = '{"name":"sample","email":"a@sample.co.uk","comments":"test"}';

/* Decode the Json (back to a PHP array) */
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

/* Loop through the keys and values of the array */
foreach ($decode as $k => $v) {
   $new_string .= $k . ' | ' . $v . '<br/>';
}

/* Show the result on the page */
echo $new_string;
```

---

The above code returns the following;

```
name | sample
email | a@sample.co.uk
comments | test
```

---

If you want to access the array values one by one you can also use the following code.

```
/* The Json encoded array.*/
$json = '{"name":"sample","email":"a@sample.co.uk","comments":"test"}';

/* Decode the Json (back to a PHP array) */
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

echo $decode['name'];//returns sample
echo $decode['email'];//returns a@sample.co.uk
echo $decode['comments'];//returns test
```